# Magento: How to build a custom image gallery in an admin form?

Tags: php, image, magento

I'm in the process of `building` a custom module to `handle our customer's submitted product testimonials`. I'm mostly done with the admin management portion of the module but am hitting a major stumbling block in understanding how to best implement the image management portion.

Just like the product management, when you edit a story, you can edit or add images associated with that story.

What I want is this:
[image: catalog_product images snapshot]
Though it will need to be custom built from scratch to suit my module's needs.

I'm using catalog_product as a reference for obvious reasons, but I don't understand how the `catalog_product` `image grid` and file uploader are `being added to the attribute's fieldset.`

What I have in the my image tab's class so far (not much) is:

```
class MyModule_Stories_Block_Adminhtml_Stories_Edit_Tab_Image
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = Mage::registry('current_story');
        $_data = $model->getData();

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('image_fieldset', array(
            'legend' => $this->_translate('Story Images'),
        ));

        $form->addValues($_data);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

I'm just asking for a point in the right direction to proceed.   Should I be creating the image grid in a custom block and add it to the form fieldset (and how *do* I add a block to a `$fieldset`)? And if I did add that block to the fieldset would I still be able to populate the any text fields in that block with the `$_data` using `$form->addValues($_data);`?

I'm kind of lost and any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Note: The answer in the Stack Overflow post, [How to include Magento Image Gallery in a Custom Module Backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740995/how-to-include-magento-image-gallery-in-a-custom-module-backend-solved), ultimately leads to a broken link and really does not provide a tangible answer with any real direction, so please don't mark this as a duplicate of that.